# Purpose of session_abort()

Tags: php, function, session

I have been checking the PHP session functions and I saw `session_abort()`.

- What is the purpose of using `session_abort()`?
- What is the difference between `session_abort()` and `session_destroy()`?

Comment: From: [PHP session_abort Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php)  `session_abort() finishes session without saving data. Thus the original values in session data are kept.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`session_abort()` is analogous to [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).

PHP locks session data during a web request to prevent data corruption on multiple simultaneous requests.

When **Request 1** comes in, **Session 1** is locked by that process so it can make any changes needed. If **Request 2** comes in for **Session 1**, php blocks until the session lock is released to make sure that **Request 2** has the most up-to-date session data.

`session_abort()` closes the session and releases the lock without flushing session data to the session storage mechanism while `session_write_close()` writes the current content of session back and then closes / releases the lock.

edit: Calling `session_abort()` or `session_write_close()` will let php process **Request 2** even if **Request 1** is not finished processing.

Comment: Thanks. When do we use session_abort()?. is it useful at all ?

Comment: It could be useful if you know session data has not changed and you want the request to stop blocking a second request.

Comment: Thanks Josh Trii Johnston .Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Useful to me

Answer (score 3):

**session_abort()** finishes session without saving data. Thus the original values in session data are kept.

**session_destroy()** destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.

References :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-abort.php

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an example ?

Comment: There are various examples posted in the above reference links, do refer them. Cheers..!!

Comment: Thanks Amit. I got it

Comment: Awesome, glad that you got it..!! Cheers..!!