# The Difference between session_abort and session_unset

Tags: php, session

I have tried to show the difference between `session_abort()` and `session_unset()` but I can't get it ..the only difference I know is that they both clear up all session content with keeping the file of the session without destroying it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565502/purpose-of-session-abort talks about session_abort vs session_destroy, that may help